# KnockoutJs - Calculate Database Ratings

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, raty

Take a look at this first:

http://pastebin.com/823NMiWc

This is Knckoutjs + Jquery Raty Plugin

Assume these are columns from a database:

```
story_rev: ko.observable(),
animation_rev: ko.obervable(),
sound_rev: ko.observable(),
characters_rev: ko.observable(),
enjoyment_rev: ko.observeable(),
```

These are basically rating based events in the database which ranges from 0-5 with a step of 0.5 (number input)

Does anyone know how to make it so that it calculates the average of the 5 ratings? I kinda know how to do it via jquery, but knockoutjs is a different story for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) to calculate the average.

```js
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
 
    self.story_rev = ko.observable();
    self.animation_rev = ko.observable();
    self.sound_rev = ko.observable();
    self.characters_rev = ko.observable();
    self.enjoyment_rev = ko.observable();
    
    self.averageRating = ko.computed(function() {
        var ratings = [self.story_rev(), self.animation_rev(), self.sound_rev(), self.characters_rev(), self.enjoyment_rev()];
        
        return ratings.reduce(function(a, b) {
            return a + parseInt(b, 10);
        }) / ratings.length;
    });
}

var model = new AppViewModel();

model.story_rev(1);
model.animation_rev(2);
model.sound_rev(3);
model.characters_rev(4);
model.enjoyment_rev(5);

//Should output the average (in this case 3)
console.log(model.averageRating());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```